# ASP.NET API/C# ObjectResult - adding more "columns" at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Below is a simplified version of a web service method that pulls a tabular data from SQL stored procedure to pass to the front end. The "allLocations" object returned by the method is of type ObjectResult. How could I add more "columns" at runtime? The values of the new columns would be inserted based on some if/else condition. Any help is appreciated.

```
    // GET: api/Locations/GetLocations
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<sp_GetLocations_Result> GetLocations()
    {

        // Initial object allLocations of ObjectResult type
        var allLocations = geoDB.sp_GetLocations(); 

        foreach (var loc in allLocations) 
        {
           // at runtime add more columns to tabular 
           // data and populate them based on some conditions
        }

        return allLocations; // allLocations object with more column now
    }
```

Example:
1) Initial allLocations

```
Country     City
France      Paris
USA         New York
```

2) Returned object after adding more columns

```
Continent           Country     City

Europe              France      Paris

North America       USA         New York
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempts to merge two ObjectResult type objects at runtime to achieve the extended tabular data structure were not successful, but I found a simple solution that I would like to share.

You basically modify the model class sp_GetLocations_Result from which geoDB was instantiated - you add one more, Continent property:

```
public partial class sp_GetLocations_Result
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; } 
    public string Continent {get; set;}
}
```

And then inside the foreach loop you assign the continent value to that property based on some if/else condition. In other words, you receive two values, city and country, from the stored procedure, and the third value, continent, is added at runtime.

```
foreach (var loc in allLocations) 
{
       if(some condition here)
       {
         loc.continent = "Europe"; // for example
       }
}
```

At the end, you get the extended tabular structure ready for the front end.